# From GridFS to FileS ystem

Tags: mongodb, meteor, gridfs

I have some files in Mongo GridFS (inserted with utilities offered by the Meteor **cfs:gridfs** package)and I want to copy them to the filesystem in order to be compliant to an internal company backup procedure.
Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongofiles with gridfs in meteor.

Mongodb provides extensive features with mongofiles. Refer to [official manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/).